# it is known that $a<1,b<1$ and $a+b> 0.5$ prove that $(1-a)(1-b)<\frac{9}{16}$

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that $a<1,b<1$ and $a+b> 0.5$ Prove that $(1-a)(1-b) \leq \frac{9}{16}$

Comment: all what I do : 2>a+b>0.5 , (1-a)(1-b)>0  (  prove (1-a)(1-b)<=9/16

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Begin writing

$$\begin{align}0&\le\left(\sqrt{1-a}-\sqrt{1-b}\right)^2\\&=(1-a)-2\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}+(1-b)\\&=2-(a+b)-2\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}\end{align}$$
Now, rearrange the inequality to obtain
$$2\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}\le2-(a+b)<2-0.5=1.5=\frac32$$
So,
$$\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}<\frac34$$
and
$$(1-a)(1-b)<\frac9{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $$A=1-a \;\; , B=1-b$$

thus $$0<A+B<\frac 32$$

You  want to prove that $$AB<\frac{(A+B)^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$a+b>0.5\implies b+0.5>1-a$

$b<1\implies 0<1-b$

Therefore, $(1-a)(1-b)<(b+0.5)(1-b)=-b^2+0.5b+0.5=-(b-\frac14)^2+\frac9{16}\le\frac9{16}.$

Answer (score -1):

The arithmetic mean of the positive numbers $1-a$, $1-b$ is $<\frac34$. Hence so is their geometric mean.